# If and Else with multiple parameters -incorrect output

Tags: javascript

with below code, I am trying to generate some message however my if and else generating incorrect output  
In Yes (all Fileds ) getting the result

```
        if (Ferver !== "Yes"&& Cough !== "Yes"&& shortnessOfbreath !== "Yes"&& otherSymptoms !== "Yes") {
console.log('You are not eligible and you can join office from tomorrow');  
        }else{
         var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
       console.log('You are eligible and you can join office from tomorrow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It checks if all the inputs to the if statement are 'Yes' assuming the inputs are all of type string (You can type-check using `typeof`).

```
if (`${Ferver}${Cough}${shortnessOfbreath}${otherSymptoms}` === 'Yes'.repeat(4)) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    console.log('You are eligible and you can join office from tomorrow');
} else {
    console.log('You are not eligible and you can join office from tomorrow');
}
```

Since 'Yes' and 'yes' are not equal, you might need to use `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase` on your variables to do a case insensitive comparison.

---

### Edit . . .

---

If you would like to add more items to the string You could store the result of the question in a variable like ***apply*** and check for it like:

```
if(`${Ferver}${Cough}${shortnessOfbreath}${otherSymptoms}${apply}` === 'Yes'.repeat(4) + 
'I have recently interacted or lived with someone who has tested positive for COVID-19'){
    // Write some code here . . .
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can add one more string in If statement
Example: Which of the following apply to you? ===I have recently interacted or lived with someone who has tested positive for COVID-19